# Leiningen, repl, uberjar: Unable to resolve symbol, No such var

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, uberjar

While my **lein new app** project runs merrily inside the Light Table, **lein uberjar** won't work. Curiously, it behaves exactly like a classic Pascal compiler: it can't resolve references ahead of definitions. Another curiosity: yesterday it worked. I am not aware of fooling with anything sensitive.

Google says that the subj symptoms are quite commonplace; I tried whatever helped other people in the same (?) plight, but to no avail. By the way, usually they blame it on software bugs: "get the latest version of Leiningen and Clojure". I've got 2.5.0 and 1.6.

The project (main file) is here: https://github.com/Tyrn/pcc/blob/master/src/pcc/core.clj
As it is, **parsed-args** can't be resolved inside **build-album**; if I move the -main function to the top of the file, 'No such var' happens to **cli-options** inside -main. No amount of fiddling with explicit use of namespaces makes any difference.

Again, inside the Light Table everything runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `def` inside of a function is not idiomatic, especially if there is no reason to have it as a global variable. Just pass it as a function parameter:

```
(let [parsed-args (parse-opts ...)]
  ...
  (build-album parsed-args))
```

If you really need global state, you can use e.g. a promise (alternatively, an atom):

```
(defonce parsed-args (promise))
...
(deliver parsed-args (parse-opts ...))
```

However, Clojure files are read from top to bottom, and yes, functions not having access to bindings introduced later in the file is by design. You can use `declare` to tell the parser what to expect:

```
(declare ^:dynamic *parsed-args*)
(defn build-album ...)
(def ^:dynamic *parsed-args* ...)
...
(binding [*parsed-args* (parse-opts ...)]
  (build-album))
```

**TL;DR:** If not necessary, avoid global state; if necessary, minimize it.

Comment: Thank you very much, **xsc**! Somehow I could not bring myself to believe that declarations might exist in such a thoroughly interpreted language. Despite the obvious.